# How did we get condition filtering value of 5 percent in this plan instead of 10 percent? MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, optimization

Assume the below schema, this is just created to test some features, and not a valid design for production. When I run the below query and check it's optimizer trace, I find lot of plans.

[image: Schema]

```sql
select 
e.emp_no, 
concat(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name), 
d.dept_name, 
t.title_name, 
es.salary, 
es.insurance, 
es.pf, 
ea.city, 
ea.state, 
ea.phone 
from employee e 
join emp_salary es on e.emp_no = es.emp_no 
join emp_title et on et.emp_no = e.emp_no 
join title t on t.title_no = et.title_no 
join emp_address_phone ea on ea.emp_no = e.emp_no 
join emp_dept ed on e.emp_no = ed.emp_no 
join department d on d.dept_no = ed.dept_no 
where 
(e.hire_date > '2004-01-01' or e.hire_date < '1980-01-01') and 
(es.pf > 4.25 or es.pf < 1.4) and 
(t.title_created > '2006-01-01') and 
(ea.country = 'Spain' or ea.country = 'Samoa' or ea.country = 'India');
```

In the first plan that is..

```
d->t->et->ed->es->ea->e
```

..there is a condition filtering value when `ed` is joined to `d->t->et` that I am unable to make sense of.

[image: Plan Trace]

I recreated this join order, with a straight join, I tried explain, and found the same.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys   | key      | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY         | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                          |  100 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY         | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                          | 1000 |    33.33 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et    | NULL       | ref    | emp_no,title_no | title_no | 5       | employee_cond_filt.t.title_no |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ed    | NULL       | eq_ref | emp_no,dept_no  | emp_no   | 5       | employee_cond_filt.et.emp_no  |    1 | **5.00** | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | es    | NULL       | eq_ref | emp_no          | emp_no   | 5       | employee_cond_filt.et.emp_no  |    1 |    55.55 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ea    | NULL       | eq_ref | emp_no          | emp_no   | 5       | employee_cond_filt.et.emp_no  |    1 |    27.10 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY  | 4       | employee_cond_filt.et.emp_no  |    1 |    55.55 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I understand

```
Filtering Factor (ea) = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.01 - 0.01 - 0.01 = 0.27 (ea.country = 'Spain'  or ea.country = 'Samoa' or ea.country = 'India' )
Filtering Factor (t) = 0.3333 (t.title_created > '2006-01-01')
Filtering Factor (es) = 0.3333 + 0.3333 - 0.1111 = 0.5555 (es.pf > 4.25 or es.pf < 1.4)
Filtering Factor (e) = 0.3333 + 0.3333 - 0.1111 = 0.5555 (e.hire_date > '2004-01-01' or e.hire_date < '1980-01-01')
```

But attached condition for `ed` is just `(ed.dept_no = d.dept_no)`. Should the filter percent be 10 or the factor be 0.1 in that case?

[image: Explain]

Full [Explain](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/m7Dz5x13) and Full [Trace](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/fUaYUKDF) for reference.